# "Use of undeclared type 'Pulseable'" error with Material 2.4.15

Tags: cosmicmind

My team is using version 2.4.15 (not the latest version) for stability.

Every time I do `pod update`, pod installs with podfile but I get the following compile errors:

[image: 'Pulseable' and 'Pulse'-related Swift Compiler errors]

Comment: Hey, can you upgrade to the latest [Material 2.5.2](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/releases/tag/2.5.2)? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was to upgrade to the latest [Material 2.5.2](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/releases/tag/2.5.2).